# How to write a formula where if the date field is not blank, to populate with text

Tags: formula, email-template, merge-field, date-field

I'm creating an email template that contains a formula where, if our date field, 'DocuSign Sent', is not blank, it should populate the date. But if it is blank, it should populate this text, "No Document Sent".

When I preview the template (testing on an Opp where this field is blank), it should display as "DocuSign Sent: "No Document Sent", but instead it's, "DocuSign Sent: ".

Here is the formula I used, any help is appreciated! I've never done this type of formula before, so I'm a bit lost:

DocuSign Sent: {!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c)), "No Document Sent")}

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong syntax. It should be: `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

Try something like that:
`DocuSign Sent: {!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c)), "No Document Sent", "Value if false. It can be empty string.")}`

Comment: Thanks! The only way I was able to get it to work was by entering it twice... like this:

{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c)), "No Document Sent", "No Document Sent")}

Would that negatively impact anything? I feel like that isn't right, and sorry for any newb responses! This is my first time making a formula like this and they aren't my strong suit (yet!)

Comment: Hi! :) In this case it does not make sense. You can write `"DocuSign Sent: "No Document Sent"` without formula and it will be the same result. Are you sure that`Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c` is not empty? ;>

Comment: Well, the purpose of the formula is to state that if the field is NOT blank, it will populate the date that's already in the field. I only want the text to show if the field IS blank. I can't just enter "DocuSign Sent: "No Document Sent" because that won't always be the case. I hope that helped to explain lol

Comment: But this `{!IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c)), "No Document Sent", "No Document Sent")} ` will always give you `No Document Sent` no matter, field is blank or is not. It returns `No Document Sent` for true and for false.

Comment: Yeah, I figured lol so what would be the correct formula to enter so that if the field has a date, the date will show, and if the date field is blank, to display the text "No Document Sent"?

Comment: `{!IF(ISBLANK(Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c), "No Document Sent", Opportunity.DS_Document_Sent_Date__c)}`